# View doesn't get updated after updates in store Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have *Store*, where I have **actions** and **mutations**

My action **loadProducts** calls the mutation **setProducts**, where I set values in state and it works fine

```
const actions = {
  loadProducts({ commit }, accountId ) {
    Products.where( { accountId: accountId } ).all().then((products) => {
      commit("setProducts", {accountId: accountId, products: products.data})
    });
  },
}
const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, {accountId, products}) {
    Vue.set(state, 'products', products);
  }
}
```

And then in my component I get the data, using **mapGetters** and **computed**

```
 computed: {
   ...mapGetters([
     'products'
   ]),
   products2() {
     console.log(this.products)
     return this.products;
   }}
```

Everything works, but then I try to update the data, it also works, I get updated state - in Vuex console I can see my updates state and new data, but the view itself won't be updated - so i Have to reload the page, to see the data appears.
I also do it via actions, mutations and getters, in mutations it looks like this:

```
replace() {
   Vue.set(state, key, val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using `mapState` instead of `mapGetters` to directly map the state `products` to your component? Do you have a getter called `products` that does some extra work?

```
...mapState([
  'products'
]),
```

Comment: it gets new data, but still no upfdate in view

Comment: Is there a reason you have a new computed called `products2 `? Is it just for logging?

Because you can directly access the mapped state `products` in the template.

`<my-component :producst="products" />`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update the question with your html ?